# Reinstalling windows on a multi-drive system, what to do with the data drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I need to wipe my Windows install by performing a clean installation.  I have two drives:

1. `C:`
2. `F:`

I have a lot of stuff on the F: drive.  If I'm thinking right, can I just unplug the F: drive from the current system, install the new Windows, and re-plug the F: drive without any need to format, etc.?  Will the newer Windows just "recognize" the drive and incorporate it?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: And by should you mean assuming everything goes right, and that I am competent to do such things right?

Comment: "assuming everything goes right, and that I am competent to do such things right?" -- exactly.

Comment: Its all on me, this is heavy. But I shall do it.

Comment: Choosing to unhook the data drive the (re)install and hooking it up later is an excellent idea (IMO), so I think you'll be good to go. ;)

Comment: Well, if you care, I have uninstalled the HDD and am trying like hell to get windows reinstalled from a bootable usb. I keep getting an error from the installed, "must provide driver devices drivers". I think it means I need a SATA driver from some searching. Ever heard of this perchance?

Comment: Yup, especially if the SATA controller is in AHCI or RAID mode. Head to the manufacturers site (of either the motherboard, or the notebook, depending on what we're talking about here), and get the driver from them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16807/discussion-between-bumskeeter-and-c007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual setup I use. As long as the drive's a valid, readable drive, and its there, it'll get picked up. If its for general file storage (or something like steam games), it should just work.

You shouldn't even need to unplug it, just make sure you don't accidentally install stuff on the wrong drive.