# Upgrading windows, finding the proper SATA drivers for the windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, sata

I am trying to reinstall windows and have an error from both a USB bootable .iso and a install CD stating that I need the SATA drivers to continue. I cannot seem to find the proper driver or how I would even go about it.

I have a EVGA Z77 FTW motherboard and an intel i5-3570k chip.

I have tried both drivers from EVGA's website for SATA6 and E-SATA also a driver from [this Intel link](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=%22ahci%20sata%20driver%22). Only the Intel download was recognized but it was not accepted as a valid driver by the install.

Is there a specific driver from the link I should get?
Is there a way I can tell what I need?

EDIT:

I ask this question specifically from an error I am encountering while installing windows 7. It gives me a very cryptic error message

> A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver
>   floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.
>
> Note: If the Windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you
>   can safely remove it for this step

From research I think that it wants SATA drivers and from a previous comment discussion [linked here](https://superuser.com/questions/804850/reinstalling-windows-on-a-multi-drive-system-what-to-do-with-the-data-drive), another user believes the same.

I am asking what driver this error message is asking for.

Comment: Windows 7 does not require any special drivers for SATA drives.  Your CPU product is not clear

Comment: Edited the cpu description. // Maybe do I mean ACHI/RAID drivers?

Comment: You tell me what you mean...But even if you mean achi windows 7 supports that out of the box.  Raid is another story

Comment: I will post an edit with a clear description of my problem.

Comment: What mode is your SATA drive (check bios for this answer ) ata or achi?

Comment: This might help [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2755139)

Comment: @Malcolm I've read through that a few times now. // I have also gone through 3 iso's, I will keep trying new ones. I will try and find the mode of my SATA

Comment: Do you get this error before the Windows installer needs to reboot or after?

Comment: Before, I select "install" and just after that the screen shows "setup" and then gives that error. It then prompts me to browse for the "driver" or insert a CD. Here is an image // http://www.prime-expert.com/articles/b06/images/vista2usb_required_cd_dvd_driver_is_missing.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a USB 2.0 port and not a 3.0 port for usb bootable installations...

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for the driver for your optical drive (DVD/CD). Device Manager under Windows or System Information under an Ubuntu live CD should be able to assist you in identifying the model and manufacturer of your optical drive, so that you can look for a driver on their website.

In the case of using a USB installer this driver missing error message itself is sometimes an error. USB stick installs on some systems result in the installer attempting to install from an nonexistent optical media instead of from the USB. This triggers a driver needed error when in fact it's just a problem with the installer. In such cases you can get around the issue by installing from a DVD instead of a USB stick, though in your case you've merely hit another wall.

Comment: I suspected this initially and thought to uninstall my CD drive; just by physical means. This didn't solve it. But your answer makes sense to me. Which is odd, I have also tried a CD installer disk, a burned iso to disk; not factory, and it gives the same error. // Is there no way to just give it a driver for its non-existent drive and "make it happy"? // Is it possible to completely format the drive from another computer and then install windows from that computer? (I have "internal HDD/SSD to USB" hardware, you can basically attach any drive as a USB device to another computer.)

Comment: Even more, I just found a "Windows 7 Ultimate Disk kit" CD from my college bookstore that I had I think for the original install. It's a fully windows factory CD and all, and it produces the same error.

Comment: Nevermind that, see my answer.